# How to exchange data between C++ and MATLAB?

Tags: c++, matlab

For the now being I am developing a C++ program based on some MATLAB codes. During the developing period I need to output the intermediate results to MATLAB in order to compare the C++ implementation result with the MATLAB result. What I am doing now is to write a binary file with C++, and then load the binary file with MATLAB. The following codes show an example:

```
int main ()
{
    ofstream abcdef;
    abcdef.open("C:/test.bin",ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary); 

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        float x_cord;
        x_cord = i*1.38;
        float y_cord;
        y_cord = i*10;
        abcdef<<x_cord<<"   "<<y_cord<<endl;
    }

    abcdef.close();

    return 0;
}
```

When I have the file test.bin, I can load the file automatically with MATLAB command:

```
 data = load('test.bin');
```

This method can work well when numerical data is the output; however, it could fail if the output is a class with many member variables. I was wondering whether there are better ways to do the job not only for simple numerical data but also for complicated data structure. Thanks!

Comment: The answer to your question depends on the complexity of the data structures you will import into MATLAB, since there are a lot of possibilities: see [Recommended Methods for Importing Data](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/import_export/br5wz4t.html). For max flexibility I would suggest [writing a MAT-file from C++](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f30937.html) but this may be an overkill, since it requires mastering the MATLAB internal data formats.

Comment: Ever think about using sockets to transder data back and forth

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the use of MATLAB engine through which you can pass data to MATLAB on real time basis and can even visualize the data using various graph plotting facilities available in MATLAB.

All you have to do is to invoke the MATLAB engine from C/C++ program and then you can easily execute MATLAB commands directly from the C/C++ program and/or exchange data between MATLAB and C/C++. It can be done in both directions i.e. from C++ to MATLAB and vice versa.

You can have a look at a working example for the same as shown [here](http://preetisblog.com/programming/cc/sampling-from-normal-distribution).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the fread command in `matlab`.  I do this all the time for exchanging data between `matlab` and other programs, for instance:

```
fd = fopen('datafile.bin','r');
a = fread(fd,3,'*uint32');
b = fread(fd,1,'float32');
```

With `fread` you have all the flexibility to read any type of data.  By placing a `*` in the name, as above, you also say that you want to store into that data type instead of the default `matlab` data type.  So the first one reads in 3 `32 bit` unsigned integers and stores them as integers.  The second one reads in a single precision floating point number, but stores it as the default double precision.

You need to control the way that data is written in your `c++` code, but that is inevitable.  You can make a class method in `c++` that packs the data in a deterministic way.

Dustin